# Subtracting one dataframe column from another dataframe column for multiple columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to subtract a column from one dataframe from another dataframe's column, and I wanted to do it for n number of columns (currently the dataframes I'm working on have 1000 columns).

Here are how the two dataframes look like:

**Dataframe 1:**

```
               branch A (pkg XYZ) | branch A (pkg ABC)| branch B (pkg XYZ)
               -------------------------------------------------------------
5/21 - 5/27           20          |        30         |        50
5/28 - 6/02           10          |        30         |        50
6/03 - 6/09           30          |        40         |        50
6/10 - 6/16           20          |        30         |        50
6/17 - 6/23           50          |        10         |        50
```

**Dataframe 2:**

```
                branch A (pkg XYZ)| branch A (pkg ABC) | branch B (pkg XYZ)
                -----------------------------------------------------------
5/21 - 5/27           3           |        5           |        50
5/28 - 6/02           2           |        6           |        50
6/03 - 6/09           3           |        7           |        50
6/10 - 6/16           1           |        2           |        50
6/17 - 6/23           4           |        0           |        50
```

If I wanted to subtract all the columns of **Dataframe 2** from **Dataframe 1**, based on if their column headers ("*branch A (pkg XYZ)*") match, what would be the most efficient way of doing this?

I tried iterating through a list of one dataframes columns and subtracting it from the other dataframe that way, but it seems inefficient.

```
  i = 0
  df1_cols = list(df1)
  while i < len(df1.columns):
       col_name = df1_cols[i]

       # df3 is an empty dataframe
       df3[col_name] = df1[col_name] - df2[col_name]

       i += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Dataframe.subtract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.subtract.html) to subtract columns in the two dataframes. We loop over columns in `df2` and if that column is found in `df1`, we perform the subtraction in that column. finally we save the result in a separate column whose name ends with "Result".

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({"branch A(pkg XYZ)":[20,10,30,20,50], "branch A(pkg ABC)":[30,30,40,30,10], "branch B(pkg X
   ...: YZ)":[50, 50, 50, 50, 50]})

In [3]: df1
Out[3]:
   branch A(pkg XYZ)  branch A(pkg ABC)  branch B(pkg XYZ)
0                 20                 30                 50
1                 10                 30                 50
2                 30                 40                 50
3                 20                 30                 50
4                 50                 10                 50

In [4]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({"branch A(pkg XYZ)":[3,2,3,1,4], "branch A(pkg ABC)":[5,6,7,2,0], "branch B(pkg XYZ)":[50,5
   ...: 0,50,50,50]})

In [5]: df2
Out[5]:
   branch A(pkg XYZ)  branch A(pkg ABC)  branch B(pkg XYZ)
0                  3                  5                 50
1                  2                  6                 50
2                  3                  7                 50
3                  1                  2                 50
4                  4                  0                 50

In [25]: for i in df2.columns:
    ...:     if i in df1.columns:
    ...:         df2[i+"Result"] = df2[i].subtract(df1[i], fill_value=0)

In [29]: df2
Out[29]:
   branch A(pkg XYZ)  branch A(pkg ABC)  branch B(pkg XYZ)  \
0                  3                  5                 50
1                  2                  6                 50
2                  3                  7                 50
3                  1                  2                 50
4                  4                  0                 50

   branch A(pkg XYZ)Result  branch A(pkg ABC)Result  branch B(pkg XYZ)Result
0                      -17                      -25                        0
1                       -8                      -24                        0
2                      -27                      -33                        0
3                      -19                      -28                        0
4                      -46                      -10                        0
```

An attempt with 1000 columns and 100 rows is quite efficient too:

```
In [40]: import numpy as np
In [41]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100, 1000)))
In [42]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100, 1000)))
In [45]: %%timeit
    ...: for i in df2.columns:
    ...:     if i in df1.columns:
    ...:         df2[str(i)+"Result"] = df2[i].subtract(df1[i], fill_value=0)
    ...:
    ...:
367 ms ± 97.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [49]: df2.head(5)
Out[49]:
          0         1         2         3         4         5         6  \
0  0.327470  0.272503  0.549897  0.119997  0.985847  0.445402  0.582878
1  0.752375  0.606053  0.223085  0.062001  0.025440  0.638872  0.188112
2  0.174401  0.944870  0.630128  0.715326  0.298661  0.285740  0.360253
3  0.095649  0.355365  0.523830  0.114555  0.342535  0.393107  0.246344
4  0.250579  0.105054  0.761075  0.574047  0.733976  0.199406  0.658025

          7         8         9  ...  990Result  991Result  992Result  \
0  0.335388  0.613710  0.104878  ...  -0.728738   0.147162  -0.841872
1  0.796243  0.709898  0.133040  ...  -0.151361  -0.400989   0.012670
2  0.009304  0.472587  0.108229  ...  -0.131590  -0.540945  -0.097455
3  0.798668  0.628953  0.701703  ...  -0.461036   0.217387  -0.363704
4  0.387475  0.152143  0.825989  ...  -0.021844   0.103296  -0.272207

   993Result  994Result  995Result  996Result  997Result  998Result  999Result
0   0.389068   0.470042   0.556146   0.705036  -0.021659   0.250586  -0.662487
1  -0.456462  -0.206587   0.691951  -0.507585  -0.430838  -0.126303  -0.001411
2  -0.018339   0.226750   0.483076  -0.581611  -0.362906   0.796857  -0.367914
3   0.323971  -0.779884  -0.306404  -0.825982  -0.065974  -0.109321  -0.023654
4   0.178328   0.600110   0.222539   0.064416  -0.110039  -0.615137  -0.261765

[5 rows x 2000 columns]
```

Comment: thank you! :) one question: when it subtracts one column from another will it automatically only subtract if the index values (of the two columns) match? or would I need to write another line in the loop checking if the two indexes are actually the same

Comment: An explicit index check is not required. The important thing is: The shape of the two dataframes is the same and so `subtract` sequentially goes from the top row to the last row whenever there is a column match.

Comment: Got it! And this would work even if the index for dataframes follows the format of "6/17 - 6/20"? I set the index to the date column, and want to make sure that each row from each column is being subtracted if and only if the date index matches. Thanks for your help again!